# Best database design using user defined fields

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have a question about the 'best' design solution in a case where a user defined table can specify the different types for an entity, yet 1 type within all these user defined types is something I want to keep record of separately, because this has a relationship to another (user defined field in a) table.

For example, there are `employees`. Employees have `functions`, defined by the user, but 1 of the functions is 'mechanic', and I want to keep records of `mechanic`, because mechanics have `skills` based on `productgroups`, which also are defined by the user, but in addition to that, mechanic skills can also be user defined!

Here is my example of tables and let me explain each individual table below:

[image]

- Employees

Employees are all the people known in the database as internal workers.

- Functions

Functions are user defined records and represents every possible function the user wish to add for an employee. Mechanic is a pre-defined function record, and also another table for that to be able to keep extra records of it.

- Employee_Functions

Junction table between Employees and Functions.

- Employee_MechanicSkills

Employees whom are set to the function "Mechanic" will have the option to choose from available skills. These skills involve custom created skills in `CustomMechanicSkills` with no link to any table whatsoever AND skills defined by `ProductGroups` (see below).

- ProductGroups

ProductGroups are user defined group of products. These group of products will need servicing and maintenance either by a supplier or own company. In case if it's the own company, it's good to know which employee has the required skill to be able to perform the maintenance for it - therefore the relation between ProductGroups and Employee_MechanicSkills. Additional MechanicSkills can also be created for the mechanic.

- CustomMechanicSkills

User defined mechanic skills. User might not only want to link mechanic skills to the existing productgroups but also additional, custom requirements, apart from the productgroups.

- Employee_CustomMechanicSKills

Junction table between Employees and CustomMechanicSkills

I've been thinking about this for a while now. In my database design, data integrity is the key, thus I tried to normalize as far as possible. But on the other hand, unneeded complexity of data structure isn't what I want either.

I'd like to hear some of your opinions and different views about the pro's and con's of this design, and maybe hear or see a better, improved design if there is. I would really appreciate input.

Thanks.

NOTE: Naming convention is not totally applied to this model yet.

Comment: I did a presentation exactly about pros and cons of different solutions for user-defined fields: [Extensible Data Modeling with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling).

Comment: Interesting! I did a bit of digging myself, but never heard of 'Serialized LOB', 'Inverted Indexes' and 'Online Schema Changes'

Answer (score 4):

1. Start with solid existing data model patterns, to minimize the need for this.

   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831

   Make sure you understand table inheritance.
2. Consider allowing the user to alter their own database schema. You could, for example, bust out some reloadable Groovy for data structures, Hibernate for DDL migrations, and Roo HTML generation and automate this.
3. Or consider XML or JSON database columns with indexing (possibly in another table). PostgreSQL 9.4 is out soon and has some good/fast JSON handling.

   Read this: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html

   and this http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling
4. Don't consider EAV except as an absolute last resort.

Think hard about the fields that you might need to index, search on, sort on, count, and what sort of data integrity you require.